# How do I can use linux server as my git host?

Tags: git

I want to use a personal server as a repository of my project. Then I want to push, pull files to or from it from our team. I had initialize git to a project to my local server, now want to push or pull from it to my local laptop. Can anyone please help??

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a full website thing (like GitLab), you can just set up remote access on your server, using SSH or HTTP(S).

git-scm.com has a lot of great info on git, including [how to set up remote access](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server). Reading about [the pros and cons of the different access methods](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Use GitLab.
Consider this link
https://about.gitlab.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your server [as a remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) in your local repository on the laptop

```
git remote add myserver 192.168.1.2:/path/to/repo.git
```

Where the last argument uses either the IP or the hostname of your server.

Once you add the remote, you can push to it:

```
git push myserver master
```